# Calculating surface cylinder integral

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

The circular cylinder $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with radius $R$ and height $2H$ and the edge $\partial \Omega$  is considered. The cylinder $\Omega$ in a cylinder coordinate system has this form $(r,\phi ,z)\in [0,R)×[0,2)×(-H,H)$.

How do I calculate following integral:

$$\int_{\partial\Omega }^{}2\lambda C\left ( \frac{r}{R^{2}} \left ( 1-\frac{z^{2}}{H^{2}} \right ) + \frac{1}{H^{2}}\left ( 1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}} \right ) \right ) \vec{n}\left ( r,\varphi ,z \right )dA$$

Comment: I assume you mean that $0 \leq \phi < 2 \pi.$

Comment: From what I can tell, something strange is happening here. By definition, $\int_{\partial \Omega}$ denotes a line integral of some sort, but you wish to integrate a scalar function times a vector field with respect to the area element. I am not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: yes i mean 2pi @Carlo